# Exasol not exporting in parallel to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, export, exasol

We have a connection in Exasol (v7.0.18) to PostgreSQL (v14) created like this

```sql
create or replace connection POSTGRES_DB to
    'jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/my_db?useCursorFetch=true&defaultFetchSize=2147483648'
    user 'abc'
    identified by <>;
```

I am running an export statement using this connection like this:

```sql
EXPORT MY_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE
    INTO JDBC AT POSTGRES_DB
    TABLE pg_schema.test_table
    truncate;
```

This works without any error.

The issue is that it runs only one insert statement in the PostgresSQL at a time. I am expecting multiple inserts running at a time in PostgresSQL.

[This documentation page](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/loading_data/best_practice.htm#DataImportExport) says `Importing from Exasol databases is always parallelized. For Exasol, loading tables directly is significantly faster than using the STATEMENT option.`

How can I make the export statement do parallel insert into PostgreSQL?

Comment: From what I read in the docs parallel execution is only supported with `IMPORT` into Exasol and only from another Exasol database or partitioned Oracle tables. See [IMPORT](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql/import.htm): *Usage Notes*. There is no corresponding parallelization  notes in [Export](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql/export.htm).